# Ubuntu 18.04 with routing but need VM bridge

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, routing, network-bridge

I have set up routing on my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop box.  I have one dedicated ethernet port for my internal network that serves DHCP.  I have my wireless NIC set up for internet access.  Network works great.  My next hurdle is getting a VM to work.  I am using Virtual Machine Manager to host the VM (16.04 server).  since both of these ports have been given the proper roles to keep the network functioning, I am unsure as to how I should create the bridge for the VM while also allowing it to be a client on my internal network.  Any help and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With VirtualBox
Simply setup the VM network adapter attached to **Bridged Adapter** with the **Ethernet** nic.

[image: VirtualBox Bridged Adapter]

Comment: Went ahead and tried with VB.  This did not work.  Unable to get DHCP from host at 192.168.18.1.  Unable to ping anything within the network.  Unable to ping 8.8.8.8.